# Printing a hex array in console

Tags: c++, for-loop, multidimensional-array, hex, nested-loops

I have a `uint8_t` type array, 4x4 dimensions, I have use nested for loops to display the array, hex values are converted to hex string through `sprintf()`.

```
void hexD(uint8_t state[4][4])
{
char x[2];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    cout << "\n";
    for(int  j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        cout << j <<"\n"; //displays the value of j
        sprintf(x, "%x", state[i][j]);
        cout << x << "\t";
    }
}
}
```

The problem is inner for loop which runs endlessly as value of j starts from 0 then 1 then 2 but instead of going to 3 it gets back to 1, j swaps between 1 and 2 thus the loop in running infinitely.

Any solutions to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your values in `state[4][4]`, you're likely to end up
overflowing the `x` array (remember, you need a place for at most `FF` (2 chars) + 1 for the terminating `'\0'`).
That's undefined behavior.
Fix it (`char x[3];`) and you should be fine. Here's an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
void hexD(uint8_t state[4][4])
{
char x[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    cout << "\n";
    for(int  j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        cout << j <<"\n"; //displays the value of j
        sprintf(x, "%x", state[i][j]);
        cout << x << "\t";
    }
}
}
uint8_t state[4][4]={
    255,255,255,255,
    0, 1, 2, 3,
    0, 1, 2, 3,
    0, 1, 2, 3,
};
int main()
{
    hexD(state);
}
```

Comment: @codekaizer for OP's `sprintf` (which isn't needed because iostream can print hex numbers too, but I kept it since it was in the question). I changed it to `cstdio` if that's what you meant.

Comment: This solved the problem, but I have a question that, since I had to continue my work, I copied the loop statements 16 times as a temporary solution. Ans I used `char x[2]` but it worked correctly,why?

Comment: @Nilesh Maybe your numbers were single-digit or the array out-of-bounds access didn't end up overwriting anything critical (what happens when your program is undefined is undefined)

Comment: '0xC0000005' is shown when there is some undefined behavior, but no such error code was on console

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` has only two spaces, but you are writing more characters into it. For example, a `0` in hex is `"00"`, two characters *plus a closing* `'\0'`.
That overwrites neighboring memory, and your `j` happens to be there and get overwritten.

Increase the size of `x[]`, and it should work.

Comment: Ok, now I'm not sure anymore. But even if not, `"00\0"` is still three characters - remember the `'\0'` at the end of each string.

Answer (score 0):

```
char x[2];
```

You only have two bytes for your "hex output" but no available space for a `null` character.

Writing more to an array with lesser capacity is *undefined behavior*.

Increase `x` array size to 3:

```
char x[3];
```

since as per [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/):

> A terminating null character is automatically appended after the
>   content.

Thus, you have a total of three characters *including* the `null` character.